# How to remove ACCOUNT and CART from website?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to remove ACCOUNT and CART from website.  Is there a way by editing the styles.css to do this?  Thanks, -John

Comment: what  you want disable checkout and account  feature from magento>?

Comment: Yes basically, my site will be content only, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

goto admin>system>configuration>Advance>Advance

**You need disable below module**

```
Mage_Checkout   
Mage_Customer   
Mage_Paygate    
Mage_Payment    

Mage_Paypal 

Mage_PaypalUk   

Mage_Persistent 



Mage_ProductAlert   

Mage_Rating 

Mage_Reports    

Mage_Review 

Mage_Rss    

Mage_Rule   

Mage_Sales  

Mage_SalesRule  

Mage_Sendfriend 

Mage_Shipping   




Mage_Tax    

Mage_Usa    



Mage_Wishlist   

Mage_XmlConnect 

Phoenix_CashOnDelivery  

Phoenix_Moneybookers
```

Comment: Thank you, it removed the CART, but the ACCOUNT remains.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is no way to remove any module, it only hides the output! If you want to disable the modules, disable them in the XML files.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable the registeration if you do not want to have any account.

1. easy way to disable account is using an extension : [link to disable registration extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-disable-customer-registration.html)
2. create module if you do not want paid extension : [How to disable frontend registration in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959131/how-to-disable-frontend-registration-in-magento#2961418)
3. create module is too complicated ? Go to path:

   > app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/

   find the login.phtml and register.phtml, create two files if not exists and change the content

Answer (score 1):

Colin did this already for you: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite